# Apple Push Notification in Erlang (or improved in Ruby?)

Tags: ruby, erlang, push, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I currently have an Apple Push Notification running on my server in Ruby.  I'd like to get one going in Erlang as I'd like to use a supervisor to keep watch over it.  Does anyone have any code that they could help me with?

Here's my Ruby code.  One thing I do not like about this current implementation is that it does not seem to stay connected - it disconnects 2-3 times a day, and it seems after I reconnect that the first push will not go through:

```
context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(cert))
context.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(cert))

def connect_sockets(server, context)
        sock = TCPSocket.new(server, 2195)
        ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock,context)
        ssl.connect

        return sock, ssl
end     

sock, ssl = connect_sockets(server, context) # this is called to initially connect and also reconnect whenever disconnected.
```

If Erlang Push isn't doable then I wouldn't mind sticking to my Ruby one as long as I can keep my connections alive, and perhaps supervise it through Erlang.  Does anyone know if any of this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

This [question on Apple Push Notifications with Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757171/how-to-send-a-push-notification-using-erlang) might also be useful for this one.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Client (with SSL support) that ships with Erlang works reasonably well ( I can't say I have battle tested it ). The relevant documentation is available [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/http.html).

1) Don't forget to perform an "inets:start()" in your application before attempting to do HTTP calls.

2) In my (small) experience, starting the 'inets' module seems to be a bit tricky: don't try starting it within your supervisor module or else your servers won't work.  I usually do 'inets:start()' in the first server module of my application before any other servers requiring HTTP are.

3) To perform the 'push' operation, I guess you would need to use the 'stream' option.

Comment: Sounds like you should generate a boot script from your dot-app file, and of course have inets as a dependent application of it.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check out the [apn_on_rails](http://github.com/markbates/apn_on_rails/tree)
project.

If you come up with an Erlang implementation, please consider sharing it with us :).

Comment: For sure :)  Thanks for the Rails lead.