# How to send a push notification using Erlang?

Tags: erlang, binary, push, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send a push notification to APNs using Erlang.
This is the code I came up with so far:

```
-module(apnstest2).
-export([connect/0]).

connect() ->
    application:start(ssl),
    ssl:seed("someseedstring"),
    Address = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",
    Port = 2195,
    Cert = "/path/to/Certificate.pem",
    Key = "/path/to/Key.unenc.pem",
    Options = [{certfile, Cert}, {keyfile, Key}, {mode, binary}],
    Timeout = 1000,
    {ok, Socket} = ssl:connect(Address, Port, Options, Timeout),

    Token = "195ec05a962b24954693c0b638b6216579a0d1d74b3e1c6f534c6f8fd0d50d03",
    Payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Just testing.\",\"sound\":\"chime\", \"badge\":10}}",
    TokenLength = length(Token),
    PayloadLength = length(Payload),

    Packet = [<<0:8, TokenLength, Token, PayloadLength, Payload>>],

    ssl:send(Socket, list_to_binary(Packet)),
    ssl:close(Socket).
```

The code doesn't take advantage of Erlang's concurrency but is just a prototype. I only want to test if I can send the push in the most simple way.

I think the problem is in the packet being sent to the APNs.
This is the binary format of a push notification:

[alt text http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Art/aps_provider_binary.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Art/aps_provider_binary.jpg)

How should I create such a packet in Erlang?
Could someone please take a look at my code and tell me where the problem is?
Also I used Erlang's SSL application to create the connection and send the data and I don't know if this is the problem or the packet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To start with, there is no need for creating a list of a single binary and then calling `list_to_binary/1` on it. You can just send the binary itself.

Also, make sure the field lengths and values are appropriate according to the protocol:

```
TokenLength = 32 = length(Token),
Packet = <<0:8, TokenLength:16/big, Token, PayloadLength:16/big, Payload>>,
ssl:send(Socket, Packet),
```

Now that we have gotten this far, we will see that length(Token) is in fact 64, not 32:
You forgot to convert the hex string for Token to a binary, so you are sending a 64 byte hex character string instead of 32 binary bytes.

So... making Payload a binary from the start, and making Token a numeric constant, you can do something like the following:

```
Payload = <<"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Just testing.\",\"sound\":\"chime\", \"badge\":10}}">>,
PayloadLength = size(Payload),
Packet = <<0:8, 32:16/big,
          16#195ec05a962b24954693c0b638b6216579a0d1d74b3e1c6f534c6f8fd0d50d03:256/big,
          PayloadLength:16/big, Payload/binary>>,
ssl:send(Socket, Packet),
```

Thanks to [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141420/christian) for pointing out a number of mistakes in the former revisions of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I see two mistakes:

- Token should be passed in binary and not in hex ascii.
- You can't use the binary syntax to turn lists into binaries.

For parsing hex to an integer and then down to binary use something like this:

```
Token = "dead",
TokenNum = erlang:list_to_integer(Token, 16),
TokenBin = <<TokenNum:32/integer-unit:8>>,
```

Build the protocol packet with something like this:

```
TokenBin = ...,
Payload = <<"Payload">>,
PayloadSize = byte_size(Payload),
Packet = <<0:8, 32:16, TokenBin/binary, PayloadSize:16, Payload/binary>>,
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use a simple library [epns(Erlang Push Notifications)](https://github.com/vkatsuba/epns)

This library can send push notification as APNS and FCM by Erlang side. How use **epns**(Erlang Push Notifications) library - you can read in **README.md**. This liblary can used as 3-rd party in project, or you can run it locally for see how this library works:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/vkatsuba/epns.git
$ cd epns
$ make
```

Retested on Erlang 20~21