# App for push notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification

Do i need to create mobile apps to send push notifications on iphone and blackberry.
Currently i have a website in written in rails and want to integrate push notifications on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone you want to push to needs to register with your server, after registering with the Apple Push server.  So yes, you need your app installed on it.  You can use http://code.google.com/p/ruby-apns-daemon/ for your server.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely look into that ruby-apns-daemon that bdares recommended, but this might be helpful, too, since it has some Ruby code [Apple Push Notification in Erlang (or improved in Ruby?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419187/apple-push-notification-in-erlang-or-improved-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

You also can use third party apps so you don't have to create new apps. There are plenty of good services, I personally recommend [Pushed](https://pushed.co) (they offers iOs, Android and Desktop Notifications, Chrome & Safari) and as they posted on Twitter: Windows + Blackberry apps are on the way.